# How do I access values of a JSON object extracted from quick.db?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to access values from a JSON object, however, its formatting won't allow me to use the traditional methods of doing so. For example the formatting would be as follows:

```
{
  "123456789" : 0
  "12345678910" : 14
}
```

How would I be able to access the name and the value of the first field? ex. 123456789 and 14. I'ved tried to `stringify` the objects and just treat it as a regular string and finding the first instance of `"` and last instance of `"` to get the name and then finding the index of `:` and adding 1 to get the value. However, I don't think it would be efficient neither fully accurate. Is there a way to convert this JSON Object to a 2D Array? to access it more easily?

EDIT: I won't actually know the IDs stored in the JSON Object, they are randomly generated, which is why I've stated my previous solutions before and I won't be able to use traditional methods. So I need to find a way to grab the name and value without actually knowing them. Which is why storing a JSON object in a 2D array would be most useful but I need to know if it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `JSON.parse` which parses a `JSON` string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string passed to to it

In case you don't know the keys a head you can use the `Object.keys` method to get the object keys.

```js
const data = JSON.parse('{"123456789": 0, "12345678910": 14}');

console.log(data[12345678910]);
console.log(data[123456789]);
 
// in case you don't know the keys a head
const keys = Object.keys(data);

console.log(data[keys[0]]);
console.log(data[keys[1]]);
```

More about `JSON.parse` in this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: I won't actually know the numbers that are listed in the array, they are randomly generated, so I won't be able to use this method

Comment: @lopetox612 -  I modified the answer to help your problem. please take a look

Comment: this allowed me to get the values. However, I still haven't gotten the name

Comment: You mean just doing something like `console.log(keys[0]);` ?

Comment: Logging using `console.log(data[keys[0]])` got me the value `0` however, I would need a way to get the name and value, so for example: `console.log(data[keys[0]])` = `123456789` and `console.log(data[keys[1]])` for example would output `0`

Comment: Apologies, I did not see your comment, yes something like that :) Thanks for your help!